# Initial load flatlist at the bottom of the list

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have created chat using this library: https://github.com/RageBill/react-native-autoscroll-flatlist

When users chat, everithing is okay, messages are showing correctly, but when reenter chat room initially chat is it at the top and after some miliseconds is scrolled to bottom (last messages).
Is it possible to load chat room messages initially at the bottom without scroll (like Facebook Messager, WhatsApp, Viber etc.). Want to prevent this behaviour: https://recordit.co/95Anloy2b0

RN: 0.64.0

AutoScrollFlatlist: ^1.10.1

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the actual code, is the chat screen still mounted when you go back to all chats screen? what kind of navigator do you use?
when you go back you can try to do `navigation.replace()` instead of `navgiation.navigate()` so it will unmount the screen

Comment: may be setting `inverted` property of FlatList would work..!

Comment: Nope, inverted just change direction of scrolling, now scroll is upwards